# C# is irritating? English too? NO!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, advertising, portuguese-stack-overflow

I was browsing on Stack Overflow, when I came across this advertisement of Portuguese beta Stack Overflow:

[image: the advertisement]

Translation:

```
C# is irritating. 
English too.

stackoverflow beta 
in Portuguese
Open to the public
```

Is this advertisement? C# isn't a bit irritating, and English too (although I think English is very difficult, as you can see).

Why have they decided to use an advertisement that goes against the majority of the users of Stack Overflow?

The problem is not they are saying bad things about C#. They should not say it about any language, especially in advertisements!

If a person says something is annoying, is not a problem. But if social media (such as Stack Overflow) says something is annoying, we can understand that all the Stack Overflow agrees and supports this opinion, which is clearly not the case ..

**P.S:**

I'm here to discuss how this advertisement can be offensive to those who like C#, English, and also how it can become an opinion of Stack Overflow as a group. 
And not to discuss que advertising was effective or not.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Any language is irritating when you can't figure out how to make it do what you want it to do. That's what makes people want to ask questions about it.

If you've never been in a position where you could not ask for help because you could not articulate yourself, I strongly suggest making sure you're exposed to it at some point in your life. It's .. well, it changes your perspective a bit, I've experienced it a few times traveling around the world as I have.

Yes, It's downright *irritating* when you need help yet can't ask for it, because nobody can understand you. That's why we built the site, and continue working to build more in areas where people do not commonly speak English *and are not likely to learn how to do so in order to be able to use a web site*.

That ad, IMHO, *perfectly* encapsulates every reason that I'd want to try SO in my native language, if it wasn't English.

***Update***

We're changing the wording. Same *intent*, which is basically "This is hard enough when there's no language barrier, maybe you'd like to try this other site ..." (which is, honestly, what we were trying to convey).

Comment: If something is *irritating* I just want to avoid it. If it's *hard*, *difficult*, *tricky*, or *challenging*, then I'm more motivated to keep trying, with a little help.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I was about to respond to that and remembered that you also work with Perl. What say ye now?

Comment: I haven't worked with Perl in years. (Java though...)

Comment: Have to check with Gabe, I'm not entirely sure there's much difference in context between 'hard' and 'irritating' .. if there is, that might be a sensible tweak.

Comment: Hard and Irritating is very different in portuguese.

Comment: @TimPost do not you think it would look better "Hard" than "irritating"?

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Hard to say really _ducks_ .. I've pinged the critters that need pinged to have a look at it.

Comment: Even if SO would become available in *all* languages, the English speaking community will still get the top place, first because most programming resources have best quality if displayed in English, second, you get more hits if you spell your search request in English, just because there are more synonyms in Google base, and third, I am yet to see a programming language that resembles any human-speaking language but English. With maybe fourth, English is an international language spoken by a lot more people than Portuguese or say French.

Comment: @TimPost there is a lot of difference in context. Saying that something is hard is admitting that it takes some effort and concentration for you to work on it. Saying that something is annoying is just a more polite way to say you hate it.

Comment: I'm Brazilian, but I still don't get the reason why we should have SO in my native language. It's pretty basic that if you want to work with IT in Brazil (or anywhere) you need to understand English. I don't know any (popular) programming language/framework that's based on any other language than English.

Comment: And who created this advert should have picked a different word than `irritante - irritating`. Although, in Brazilian Portuguese, it would sound more like `difficult`, which causes you stress, so, irritation.

Comment: `If you find it difficult to develop in C# and on top of that you can't even understand English, then come to the Brazilian SO, it would be easier for you`. That's the real meaning.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob "Hard" was one of our choices when we were creating this ad, but we were afraid it could possibly be seen as calling Portuguese speakers on the site stupid. As if they couldn't speak well enough to function here.

Comment: @Gabe I agree with you when you said it could be offensive, but you probably had lots of ideas to create an ad, and that came up. I'm Brazilian and I don't think english nor C# is hard or annoying, but I do believe that this ad can be misunderstood by other Brazilians.

Comment: @Vesper. We've had that argument. The Anglo-only side lost. Give up, and stop carping in comments every time Portuguese SO is mentioned. *That's* irritating.

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira We had a few different ideas for that ad, and it was always meant to be... provocative, in a way. I think C is irritating, but I love it dearly. "Irritating" was the one we believed wouldn't be taken wrongly and, obviously, we were wrong.

Comment: @TRiG I'm not saying Portuguese SO is not needed. And on a side note, you probably mixed me with someone else.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, if you don't get the [market value](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho) of having a [pt.so], that's ok, [se] does. And I hope you don't flip out if I tell you that Turkish, Russian and Spanish versions are just waiting their turn to launch :P

Comment: Seems to me like the problem is phrasing them as *statements*. I think it'd go over a lot better if you changed them to questions. *"Frustrated by C#?"* doesn't have an implied value judgment. It also seems more catchy, at least to an English speaker. I don't know Portuguese.

Comment: @brasofilo That's OK. Looking from this point it makes sense. :)

Comment: @Vesper "you get more hits if you spell your search request in English", well, that's kind of the point of the portuguese site, isn't it?

Comment: `Any language is irritating when you can't figure out how to make it do what you want it to do.` I disagree. When my compiler doesn't do what I'm trying to tell it to do, my first thought isn't "damn", it's "now the game is afoot...". It's adorable when the compiler plays hard to get.

Answer (score 18):

You haven't gotten the irony. Or your translation is too literal. Or both.

For me, the message is clear:

> You have problems with C#? You have problems with English too?
>   StackOverflow in Portuguese is the solution.

Does it really sound so bad?

Comment: in portuguese is not cleary this irony. I understood the purpose of the ad, I'm here to discuss how this can be offensive to people who do not understand

Comment: If in portuguese was written with the same word of your message, would be very good.

Answer (score 7):

I think the point of the ad is simply a sort of "tongue-in-cheek" play on words, as mentioned in a comment above, to promote the use of the Portuguese language site.

Basically, saying C# (likely a popular programming language they are dealing with) is hard enough without having to learn English, too.

It's kind of like saying, "*xyz* is annoying...so is [discussing it in] Pig Latin."  The implication is let's find an easier way to discuss.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, but this way the announcement can become offensive to some people.

Comment: I'm irritated simply over the ease with which so many people get irritated by trivial things.

Comment: For the most part, I agree with that.  But, we've all probably had moments of irritation where we think, "Why won't this program just do what I want it to do instead of what I told it..."

Answer (score 6):

I take more offense at the "C# is irritating" than the "English is annoying" part. If you're not a native\"fluent second-language" speaker, it must be annoying to find so much content on the web being in a foreign language. Just imagine if every English web page was in French or Hindi. The horror.

The reason why I don't agree with the "C# is irritating" bit is because it blames the language when the problem really is your lack of knowledge of it. But I guess many programmers in Brazil (which is where most Portuguese people reside) must have a mentality where they get forced into a profession\choice of language and it's a "cultural norm" (or at least more acceptable) to dislike programming while having a job as a programmer. In that case, this ad might make sense. Again, I'm inferring a lot from the ad, and it's hard to do that when you're not of the target demographic.

Answer (score -14):

Because is the most effective advertisement, the ones that stuck in your head and even makes you share it. The purpose of the ad has been broadly accomplished

Comment: Yeah, its really, but I'm here because this can may offend some people, and not to say that advertising was effective or not.

Comment: So it's ok for you to make offensive ads as long as you get the publicity for it? Who are we going to offend next - muslims, jews, blacks, the chinese...?

Comment: I think this is not offensive, except maybe for the C# creators.
Is really this ad insulting any person?
For example for me, [@Renan](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2263584/renan), it's really irritating when people says for me something I didn't. I was responding the question, not expressing myself.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really a very good argument. I would say a poster that was nothing but giant bolded racial slurs against as many different nationalities as I could think of, would definitely stick in your head, and you would definitely share it (in outrage), but I don't think it would get very many people to want to use your product. (This isn't anywhere near as bad as that, but your argument would apply equally.)